# How to use other languages (e. g. Russian) in VSCode + Vim + Ubuntu without changing layout by self?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I tried ibus and xkb-switch (from [im-select](https://github.com/daipeihust/im-select#linux-1)), but these don't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding to VSCode settings.json:

```json
{
    "vim.autoSwitchInputMethod.enable": true,
    "vim.autoSwitchInputMethod.defaultIM": "0",
    "vim.autoSwitchInputMethod.switchIMCmd": "/usr/bin/gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \"imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[{im}].activate()\"",
    "vim.autoSwitchInputMethod.obtainIMCmd": "/usr/bin/gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \"imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().currentSource.index\" | cut -d\"'\" -f2"
}
```

Default input method (in settings "vim.autoSwitchInputMethod.defaultIM") can be obtained by the last command in the list above (if type this command in terminal)